# std::swap loses information used by Type-Based Alias Analysis?

Tags: c++, libstdc++, strict-aliasing

By examining the implementation of the `vector` class in the GCC headers (`stl_vector.h`), I found the following two member functions inside the vector base implementation class (Which I renamed in the example as `Data_Class` to avoid long_and_weird name).

```
    void
    _M_copy_data(Data_Class const& __x) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
    {
      _M_start = __x._M_start;
      _M_finish = __x._M_finish;
      _M_end_of_storage = __x._M_end_of_storage;
    }

    void
    _M_swap_data(Data_Class& __x) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
    {
      // Do not use std::swap(_M_start, __x._M_start), etc as it loses
      // information used by TBAA.
      Data_Class __tmp;
      __tmp._M_copy_data(*this);
      _M_copy_data(__x);
      __x._M_copy_data(__tmp);
    }
```

The members (`_M_start`, `_M_finish`, `_M_end_of_storage`) are just pointers of some type and are the only members in the class.

The question here is what is the reason for the comment in the second function?
It may be for the same reason, but why not use `std::swap` for two `Data_Class` objects or maybe at least an automatically generated `operator=` to do the copying?

I feel like this could be done simpler.

Comment: I removed the last question. I put it there in the first place because I think (not sure) `std::move`ing a pointer could indicate that the old pointer does not point to that memory any more and could be useful information for optimizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a `std::vector` object, the three contained pointers will never address the same memory as the pointers in another `std::vector` - each manages its own contiguous memory region.  This insight can be used for type-based aliasing optimisations, which continue to be possible if the individual pointers are moved around in a way the compiler's able to follow and reason about.

`std::swap` may be implemented using some in-place bitwise trickery such that the compiler can't perform that tracking (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm)), so is best avoided.

Of course, there's nothing inherently preventing an optimiser from being able to track whatever `swap` does and recognising it as the same logical operation as the `__tmp`-using code, but whomever made that comment and the choice not to use `std::swap` probably observed or deduced that it wasn't optimised as well on *at least* one version of the compiler they used, for some optimisation level.  Worse optimisation could be quite common though.

The same type of observation/reasoning may have led them to avoid a default `operator=`.  For example, say the implementation on their compiler may have been akin to a `memcpy` - if you treat the data as having `char` type then you're safe against aliasing bugs (same way you can only safely sequence access to distinct `union` members is one is a `char` or `char[]`), but that's because aliasing optimisations are suppressed.

Comment: I am surprised they do not have a compiler intrinsic that guarantees a generalized `restrict` (pointers to fundamental types permitted)

Comment: @AndyG: most compilers have non-Standard extensions for restricted pointers (e.g. [GCC's](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html)), but having coded to tell the compiler pointers are to distinct memory, you don't want the compiler to lose that insight unnecessarily as it optimises.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: Having a compiler lose sight of optimization opportunities isn't as bad as having it lose sight of constructs that would make certain "optimizations" inappropriate. Both clang and gcc seem to treat aliasing as an equivalence relation rather than a directed relation; if two pointer expressions compare equal, clang and gcc are apt to replace the more complicated one with the "simpler" one, without keeping track of how the replaced pointer expression was derived.